# Is there a way to set tcl/tk canvas minsize?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a pop-up, which is a canvas, for which I wish to allow the user to drag it out to any size they wish, however it can collapse to something very small and unusable. Is there a way to set a canvas minsize? (e.g. like "wm minsize") Hopefully the answer is not to embed the canvas "in a window".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural minimum size for a canvas is 1×1.

Typically, the actual minimum size for a canvas is set up by the geometry manager; since most of the time you want to use a `grid` for containing a canvas (so you can arrange scrollbars right) setting the minimum sizes for the relevant row and column are the key thing:

```
set master .
set canvas .canv

# Go for a minimum size of 400x200
grid columnconfigure $master $canvas -minsize 400
grid rowconfigure    $master $canvas -minsize 200
```

The `pack` GM doesn't allow you to specify the minimum size at all; it uses a layout model that doesn't have that concept. The `place` lets you say everything directly, but doesn't really help in most situations. If you're embedding the canvas in another widget (e.g., in a text widget) there might be other options.

Note that you can't *actually* force the system to obey the minimum size directives you give. They're just (really strong) hints. (You might want to also look into the `wm minsize` command to control the requested sizing of the overall toplevel window, but that's independent; the minimum sizing of the widget isn't the minimum sizing of the overall container, though they can interact.)